# Gap in testing random forest using samples with different construction

Tags: sampling, random-forest

I'm using a random forest to predict a true/false classification. I have roughly 20,000 registers per month over a year. If I leave out of my train set a random 20% of the data, I get ~40% KS. If instead one month's data as test, and train with 1, 3, 6 or 11 months, it sinks to ~30%, no matter what choices or combinations I make (ie: test the last month with 11 months train, test the 7th month with 3 months train, etc.)

I tried looking at the frequencies of factor variables and the descriptives of numeric variables but there doesn't seem to be any huge differences accross the months. None of my variables points directly to the number of the month so I really don't understand why there is such a large difference between the two results.

Do you have any ideas or details I could look at to find out why this is happening?